# Communicating with an external app from within excel

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba

I am building a VB.net application that communicates with a software using API.

people need to work on data in an excel sheet,create CSV files and import it into the software and use it for analytics.

The idea is to have an excel addin,this addin would communicate with the vb.net application and then the vb.net would take care of the processes.the vb.net app would be running on the system so that it can continue to do the processes even if Excel is closed.

: I have been reading about WCF and COM ,my applications are to reside on the same computer,what would be the simplest way to do this and how?

Comment: Yes, there is a way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

COM. But .NET is designed to replace COM eventually. Anyway Excel is controllable by any COM app. If you expose COM classes in .NET then Excel can control your app.

```
Set xlBook = GetObject("C:\Users\David Candy\Documents\Super.xls")
For each wsheet in xlbook.worksheets
    msgbox wsheet.name
next
```

Is VBScript (and thus will work in VB.NET).